# How to extract the activator variable of a Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

I have created a jenkins job. I need to send mail to the person who activated the job.

Is there a variable that holds the person who activated the job?

Answer (score 0):

[This Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) provides a set of environment variables that describe the user who started the build.

Disclaimer: never used the plugin myself.